# Enum values to string list with filter

Tags: c#, linq

I need to return only the values from 1 omitting the Ant

```
    public enum AnimalCodeType
{
    Ant = 0,
    Koala = 1,
    Panda = 2,
}
```

The below code gets me all values.. How do I change it

```
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnimalCodeType)).Cast<AnimalCodeType>().Select(v => v.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnimalCodeType)).Cast<AnimalCodeType>().Where(v => v != 0).ToList();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return Enum
    .GetValues( typeof(AnimalCodeType) )
    .Cast<AnimalCodeType>()
    .Where( v => (int)v > 0 )
    .Select( v => v.ToString() )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

This gives you all but the ant (recommended way):

```
var animalsWithoutAnt = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnimalCodeType)).Cast<AnimalCodeType>()
    .Where(act => act != AnimalCodeType.Ant)
    .ToList();
```

or by using the int-value:

```
var animalsWithoutAnt = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnimalCodeType)).Cast<AnimalCodeType>()
   .Where(act => (int)act != 0)
   .ToList();
```